# How do I make my horizontally scrolling page work in IE?

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, scroll

I am using a horizontal scroll for a page on my website ~ works great in FF but not in IE, how can i get it to work in IE? Here is the JS that I have in the head of my html:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
        $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
        $(".post").wrap("<td>");
    });</script>
```

There is also of course the other script file, but its huge so I'm not going to post it here. Is there a hack or something I can use to get it to scroll correctly in IE? Thx in advance!

Comment: Off topic, but just wanted to make sure you knew that you're using quite an old version of jQuery. Version 1.4.2 is the current release with many feature and performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

That look like a hack. You're basically placing the content in a table cell which apparently has a overflow. Why don't you just set the overflow on the `#page-wrap` or `.post` element itself?

```
#page-wrap {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Maybe more CSS properties are needed, but that depends on the complete context which is unknown as far.